# Null Pointer Exception write Jtable to Excel

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, jtable

I'm trying to write date  from a  Jtable to Excel.

This is my public void to do it:

```
public void toExcel(JTable table, File file){
    try{
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        FileWriter excel = new FileWriter(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++){
            excel.write(model.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
        }

        excel.write("\n");

        for(int i=0; i< model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                excel.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
            }
            excel.write("\n");
        }

        excel.close();

    }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }
}
```

and this is how i let my code do it:

```
JMenuItem Save = new JMenuItem("Save gegevens");
        Open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                toExcel(table, new File("Resultaten1.xls"));
            }
        });

        mnNewMenu.add(Save);
```

But whatever i change in my code or whatever i try, i always get a NullPointer Exception and my created file is always empty.. Does someone know what i do wrong or should add to my code?

Comment: Where (which line) exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: excel.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");

Comment: But what should i do then? i have an app that writes data to the jtable after hitting a button and there is certainly data in the jtable when i hit the button to save the jtable?

Comment: @VanpeltJ Do you have values in all cells in your table?

Comment: I both have values and text in the cells. It's a table to show results of a tennis game...

Comment: It seems that i should not have initialized the model. after removing this it works now.. Thank you for letting me realize that the model was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.getValueAt(i,j)` may return null so you should check for null before using the returned value:

```
if (model.getValueAt(i,j) != null)
    excel.write(model.getValueAt(i,j).toString()+"\t");
```

Comment: I have added this now and at least i don't have a Null exception anymore. and i removed the initialization of the model and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`model.getValueAt()` is `null` so you get this exception.

```
NullPointerException:

Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

 - Calling the instance method of a null object.
 - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
 - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
 - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
 - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
```

So you should check to avoid using `null` when you call `model.setValueAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ".toString()" call. Java will automatically use to string in this expression, and if there is a null - you will see where the null is in your file. This way you can avoid using  empty rows/columns or rethink which values you would like to output to the excel.

NPE check would do it either - just you will not understand where the missing data is.